# Output a PDF as a byte array or stream

Tags: pdftex, compiling, output, terminal-output

Is it possible for pdflatex to output a PDF as a byte array or stream, rather than writing the bytes to disk?

I want to repeatedly write a PDF and immediately extract it's text; if I can avoid writing to disk and then reading from disk, everything will run faster.

Comment: If you're just extracting the text, why are you going through pdf in the first place. That sounds cumbersome.

Comment: Yes, it's cumbersome. I want to know how many lines a given string fills in a tabular environment. As far as I know the only way to reliable do this is to add lineno, output a PDF, and extract the text. If there's a way to count lines without outputting a PDF, that would be the optimal solution.

Comment: Why are you adding amounts of text into a tabular in the first place? That sounds like a suboptimal design. Perhaps you should describe what you're actually doing and perhaps people here can come up with a better solution.

Comment: I want to procedurally generate Talmud-esque layouts. At most points in the algorithm, the generator needs to know the number of lines a block of text would fill given a column width. For example, the left and right columns typically wrap the center column in four lines of text: https://w3.chabad.org/media/images/1009/NtXl10096055.jpg Im handling the algorithm in python, but I need to know the dimensions of a block of text. It's less important that it's tabular, I suppose. Paracol would probably be better, but this particular problem would remain.

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to do a layout looking like that from tabulars. I would probably ask a question on whether or not a layout like that is feasible through lualatex.

Comment: I can do it. In fact, I'm doing it now with latex+python. It's hacky and slow but it works. If I could skip writing to disk it would still be hacky but faster.

Comment: That is why I encourage you to ask help on actually solving the problem, typesetting Talmud like pages. There might be better ways without all the hacking. It is also why I mention lualatex.

Comment: Hmm ok. Luatex looks like it might be helpful... thanks

Comment: Which what those who know how to use the Lua part can actually do with lualatex, it is quite impressive. Sadly I'm not one of them.